# Why can I assign a C block to an incompatible typedef in LLVM compiler/Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, llvm

I am working on an iOS app and then I've realized that I was making a serious error when assigning C blocks to a typedeffed block pointer type with incompatible signature.

Here is the weird part: it doesn't give any errors or warnings, compiles, and runs perfectly.

Here is my typedef:

`typedef void (^ULAction)();`

Any `ULAction` object should be a C block that takes no arguments, and returns no value. I've forgotten about the signature, and at some point in my app, by mistake, I have many assignments like this:

```
ULAction preAction = ^(id result){
    //just some code that uses the variable 'result'
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] ...];
};
```

The signature of the C block and the type don't match, but the code runs perfectly. I don't get any warnings or errors. The variable `result` is used, valid, and doesn't crash in any way. It just works.

I wonder why this is the case.

Comment: @trojanfoe it's already in the question?

Comment: Why it works is obvious -- you're matching your call with the block signature.  That you don't even get a warning is very strange, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty parameter list means you can pass any number of parameters.

I think things would be different if you defined the block as:

```
typedef void (^ULAction)(void);
//                       ^^^^
```

Comment: that was it. I didn't know about that. I changed the definition to your suggestion and I've immediately got compiler errors about incorrect assignments.